# Filling in holes in a wooden porch frame made by bees

Tags: wood, hole, wood-filler, sunroom

I have a question on filling in holes on the post of my sunroom.
left image: sunroom and a hole on the red box.
right image: a hole (on the red box).
The hole is about a half depth of the post.
Would you mind letting me know how to fill out the hole?
There are some holes which were made by bees. Maybe, carpenter bees.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that you can fill the holes, but the bees will return and make new ones regardless of your action. I had to cover an affected area with wire mesh screening to eliminate the drilling. The previously implanted bees ate their way out of the holes and perished under the screen, but options were/are limited.

Comment: you should spray insecticide into the hole before patching. Triazicide works well.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two that come to mind:

1. Drill the tunnel out to a larger, perfectly round shape. Glue a piece of wood dowel into the hole as a plug. It's not necessary to completely fill the hollowed space -- it would be good enough to make the plug as little as 1/4 inch thick.
2. Obtain or create some sawdust with a color similar to this wood. Mix it with epoxy, press it into the hole, and place plastic packaging tape over the hole to hold the epoxy (prevent it running out) until the epoxy has set.

Comment: Depending on how critical it is that the patching be invisible, I'd really suggest #1. Drill it to the exact size of the dowel, squeeze the glue in, tap the plug in but leave it standing proud just a bit. Cut it flush once the glue has dried. Staining would be an issue though, even if sanded all the wood down and restained the whole thing, you'd have an end-grain absorbing stain differently than the long grain. Check out [woodworking.se] for a _ton_ of staining/finishing tips.

Answer (score 2):

If you these are due to Carpenter Bees, and I think they are, there are bee larvae inside the hole that you should deal with before sealing it.  Otherwise they will hatch and drill their way out.

You can buy a insecticidal dust or a foaming "spray" that will travel around the corners and get to the larvae.   You can find treatments from online DIY pest control vendors.

You can fill the exterior hole anyway that works for you.  Cork plugs, wood dowels, etc.
I use cheap Bondo-like stuff.  But then sand and paint the board.

Carpenter Bees prefer unpainted wood surfaces.  If you can, paint them.  Their offspring will come back to look for a place for themselves.  You have to keep at it for awhile.